# How do I cc myself on every email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Where can I find the settings to automatically cc myself on all sent email in outlook 2013?

Comment: Brillant! I was not as simple as the holders version. Tanks David

Comment: Can you tell me the point of doing this? Just interested.

Comment: I cc myself because I'm using both windows and mac mobiles and pc(s) with différents email. I don't want every machine receiving all emails from every adresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I automatically copy myself on all sent email in outlook 2013?

> 1. Launch your outlook 2013 or 2010, and make sure that you are in the mail section. Then click Home > Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts.
>
>    [image]
> 2. After selecting Manage Rules & Alerts option, the Rules and Alerts dialog will popup. Under E-mail Rules, click New Rule option.
>
>    [image]
> 3. In the Rules Wizard, click Apply rule on messages I send then click Next to continue.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Then another dialog pops up.
>
>    - In Step 1, check through the specified account box. In Step 2, please click on the word - specified.
>    - And then click the Account drop down list to choose the account that you want to apply this rule. 
>        [image]
>
>    [image]
> 5. After selecting the account, and click OK to return to the previous window, you will see the selected account showing in the Rules Wizard.
>      Then click on Next button.
>
>    [image]
> 6. - In this wizard, check Cc the message to people or public group box, and then click on people or public group in step 2.
>    - In the Rule Address dialog box, double click your cc recipient to add the address to the To-> text box, (If I want to cc myself, I will
>        select or type my own email address in the To-> column.), finally
>        click OK. 
>        [image]
>        
>        [image]
> 7. It returns to the previous window, and you can see the cc recipient address appearing. Then click Finish button. See screenshot:
>
>    [image]
> 8. Now, it returns to the very beginning dialog, click OK button, then the cc rule will be created. If you don’t want to enable the rule,
>      uncheck it.
>
>    [image]
>
>    Then after sending or forwarding an email message to others with your
>      specified account, your account or your specific cc recipient will
>      always receive the same message.

Source [How to automatically cc myself always in Outlook?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1108-outlook-auto-cc.html)